# How to avoid assigning child instances to parent class type variables at declaration with Structural Search command in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, structural-search

I'm trying to create an inspection based on Structural Search
to avoid initializing ExecutorService to Executor Variables.

The below is my template:

```
<searchConfiguration name="Use an ExecutorService variable to initialize instead of Executor" text="Executor $x$ = $y$;" recursive="true" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" >
<constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
<constraint name="x" nameOfExprType="java\.util\.concurrent\.Executor" within="" contains="" />
<constraint name="y" nameOfExprType="java\.util\.concurrent\.ExecutorService"  within="" contains="" />
```

The code which I want to avoid such initializations:

```
 private final Executor exec = Execs.singleThreaded("test-%s");
```

The structural search is not working as I expected. What's wrong with my template?

Answer (score 0):

I removed "nameOfExprType" of x. It worked.

```
<searchConfiguration name="Use an ExecutorService variable to initialize instead of Executor" text="Executor $x$ = $y$;" recursive="true" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" >
    <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
    <constraint name="x"  within="" contains="" />
    <constraint name="y" nameOfExprType="java\.util\.concurrent\.ExecutorService" exprTypeWithinHierarchy="true"  within="" contains="" />
  </searchConfiguration>
```